# Want to remove Double Quote from both sides of the string "1,62099"?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, string

If my string is "1,60299" getting collection of UserCodes .... then if I want to remove " from both ends what do I have to do ??

ex: `strUserCode = "1,62099,100156321"`

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make sense, what data type are you wanting to use other than a string (which is encapsulated by quotation marks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **replace()** function

Or you can use **LTrim(), RTrim()** functions

*if I understood you correctly that you are using vb.net*

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `String.Replace(String, String)` Method, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

[String.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Something like this -

```
Dim errString As String = "Example String " & """" & "This is the String with double quotes." & """"

Console.WriteLine("The original string is:{0}'{1}'{0}", Environment.NewLine, errString)

' Correct the spelling of "document".  
Dim correctString As String = errString.Replace("""", "")

Console.WriteLine("After correcting the string, the result is:{0}'{1}'", Environment.NewLine, correctString)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `strUserCode.Trim('"');`